# Call server side method with non-array args using SignalR-ObjC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, signalr

I am trying to call a server side method with non-array args using SignalR-ObjC. The method is called Subscribe, but the way I am calling it is asking for an array, while my server's method takes a string. Is there another way to pass args to a server side method using SignalR-ObjC?

Code for reference:

```
SRHubConnection *hubConnection = [SRHubConnection connectionWithURLString:@"xxx"];

SRHubProxy *proxy = [hubConnection createHubProxy:@"xxx"];

// Register for connection lifecycle events
[hubConnection setStarted:^{
    NSLog(@"Connection Started");
    [proxy invoke:@"Subscribe" withArgs:resultsArray[0] completionHandler:nil];

}];
```

Comment: Have you tried putting arguments into the array like they do here: https://github.com/DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC/blob/c412cc38618b27c83fe170eaa9da95aa0c7eb42a/Example/Networking/MouseTrackingConnection.m#L52? There is no strong binding between the client and the server so the client never knows how many parameters the server method takes. Using an array allows invoking a server method with the same client API regardless of how many parameters the server method takes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Pawel pointed out, putting the arguments into array solved the problem. This is how I did so:

```
 [proxy invoke:@"Subscribe" withArgs:@[resultsArray[0]] completionHandler:nil];
```